# How to disable sorting import order by prettier in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

.prettierrc is like below

```js
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "semi": false
}
```

I think this config file is working in vscode
(I test semi to true, then prettier add semi colon each lines)
but the problem is prettier change import order in all files
for example,

When I run prettier, this changed

```js
import Test from 'renewal/features/test'
import type { FC } from 'react'

const App: FC = () => {
  return <div><Test /></div>
}

export default App
```

to this

```js
import type { FC } from 'react'
import Test from 'renewal/features/test'

const App: FC = () => {
  return <div><Test /></div>
}

export default App
```

import order is changed to alphabetical order.
In Webstorm, this is not happened
How can I disable this feature?

Comment: I just hit this same problem. It happened after installing the prettier-import-sorter plugin, and even after uninstalling it now I can't remove this import sorting... I removed all the VS Code cache there is and still this auto import sorting applies...

Answer (score 2):

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll": "explicit",
   // "source.sortImports": "explicit"
},
```

I have right now the same issue, I've solved it by commenting the `source.sortImports` property in my VSCode Open User settings file (Command+P -> >Open User Settings)

I beleive it will help you!